# Set the configuration file using dataclass such that some variables can be mutable and some varaibles are immutable

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, config, python-dataclasses

I would like to write a configuration file for the AWS services e.g.: `BucketName, job name, etc` such that the file is configurable by the user if required.

These are some of the works I have carried using the `dataclasses`. Setting the `frozen=True` to dataclass, all the variables are immutable.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass(frozen=True)
class AWSConfiguration:
    
    bucket = {"bucket_name": "s3:///abc/"}
    jobqueue = {"job_def_name": "aws_service"}
```

writing a value to variable of the class:

```
AWSConfiguration().jobqueue = "a"
```

It throws the following error:

```
FrozenInstanceError: cannot assign to field 'jobqueue'
```

Is there a way such that I can make just the variable `bucket` as immutable and `jobqueue` mutable

Comment: Not without adding `__setattr__` code to check for that.  Is it really worth the trouble?  You could always add a second data class for your mutable configuration.

Comment: Why are you using `frozen=True` on the dataclass anyway? Note that it takes slightly longer to create frozen dataclasses, rather than just regular dataclasses.